# Syntax error name 'username' is not defined python 3

Tags: python-3.x

My problem is i have multiple def statements login register dice. and im trying to call a variable from the registration statement to the dice statement but it says username is not defined when it is.

```
def register():# registers users
    myfile = open ('User names.csv','a+')
    print('\n~~Registration~~\n\n')
    username = input('Enter your username\n')
    password = input('Enter your password\n')
    new_data = username+','+password
    myfile.write (str(new_data))

def dice():
    player_1_username = username
```

It says name 'username' is not defined

Comment: `username` is a local variable in `register`. It's not visible in `dice`.

Comment: `username` isn't defined.  Where do you think the value of `username` should come from in the `dice` function?  Keep in mind that it's entirely possible that someone will use the `dice` function without ever using the `register` function

Answer (score 1):

The variable username is scoped to register function only and is not accessible within dice function.You have to pass username to dice function as a parameter or make username to be global outside the function in order to access it.

Comment: how would i make it global

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make your 'username' variable global.

```
   global username
   username = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Then try this:

```
  def register():# registers users
            myfile = open ('User names.csv','a+')
            print('\n~~Registration~~\n\n')
            username = input('Enter your username\n')
            password = input('Enter your password\n')
            new_data = username+','+password
            myfile.write (str(new_data))
            return username

  def dice():
            player_1_username = register()
  dice() #you must call the function too
```

Comment: u don't understand my program

Comment: https://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/503195-programming-project-tasks-june-2019-and-june-2020.pdf. im trying task 3